# Transfer of UK Savings to USA

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, money-transfer, tax-free-savings

Since their birth (10 years) I have been saving money into a tax free account for my grandchildren in a UK bank. I now wish to transfer the lump sum to them in USA. They have UK and US citizenship as an American mother and British father.
Can the tax-free status be maintained or are there taxation implications in the USA?

Comment: Is the UK account in your name only?

Comment: Ganesh, the account has two signatories, me and another, in the name of the child

Comment: What kind of account is it?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult (impossible?) to properly answer this question without knowing more about what kind of account it is.  Based on "tax free" I'd have guessed a JISA (Junior ISA) or a Child Trust Fund but I'm not sure that can fit with the "two signatories" one of whom is a grandparent.  Or is it not actually tax free but just a regular savings account paying interest gross?

In any case, I fear you may be sadly mistaken about its tax free status for the US citizen part-owner.  US citizens (including children) are subject to "worldwide taxation" and my understanding is that the IRS does not recognize things like the JISA tax-free status.  (There's an interesting read at this "[What Americans in the UK need to know about taxation for children](https://www.buzzacott.co.uk/insights/stepping-stones-what-americans-in-the-uk-need-to-know-about-taxation-for-children)" page which gives some idea of the complexities involved, but which may also offer some solutions e.g a "section 529 college plan" is mentioned).